# How can I get an image from the drupal 9 api?

Tags: reactjs, drupal

Good morning young people, I am doing an internship in React Native and what I want to do is take an image from the Drupal 9 API but the truth is that I have not been able to do it, I have done almost everything and I cannot solve it, I really hope that I can you help thank you very much

```html
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { Layout,Text,Card, Button } from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { StyleSheet,Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

const URL_BASE = 'https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/jsonapi/node/productos'

const InventoryDairy = () => {

  const [productos, setProductos] = useState({})
  const [imagen,setImagen] = useState({})

  let inventario = Object.values(productos)
  const getDary = () => {
    //llamada axios para obtener los productos
    axios.get(URL_BASE, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      setProductos(response.data.data)
      console.log('>>>',response.data.data[0].relationships.field_imagen.data.id,'<<<<<<') 
      setImagen(response.data.data[0].relationships.field_imagen.data.id)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
   useEffect(()=> {
    getDary()

   },[])
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Text style={styles.titleMain}>Inventario Lacteos</Text> 
      {      
        inventario.map((producto,index)=>{
          return(
            <>
              <Card key={index} style={styles.card} status='primary'> 
                <Layout style={styles.productsInformation}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}><Text>Proveedor:</Text> {producto.attributes.field_proveedor}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{producto.attributes.title}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.title}><Text>Precio:</Text> ${producto.attributes.field_precio_venta}</Text>
                </Layout>
                <Layout style={styles.productsPhoto}>
                 <Image
                  source={producto[0].relationships.field_imagen.data.id} //here <====
                 />
                </Layout>
                <Text key={index} style={styles.title}><Text>Inventario :</Text> {producto.attributes.field_inventory}</Text>
              </Card>
            </>
          )
        })
      } 
      
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I'm getting the error that it can't find the relationships when I want to do it dynamically, but when I do it with just one I don't get that message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that yout are trying to set the `source` of image before the request is done. Try change this part of code to this:

```
<Layout style={styles.productsPhoto}>
  {imagen &&
    <Image source={imagen} />
  }          
</Layout>
```